# initializer element is not a compile-time constant with malloc

Tags: c

I am writing a C program, but I get the following error for the pvowels pointer:

```
[cquery] initializer element is not a compile-time constant
```

Here is the code:

```
int n = 5;
char *pvowels = (char *) malloc(n * sizeof(char));

pvowels[0] = 'A';
pvowels[1] = 'E';
*(pvowels + 2) = 'I';
pvowels[3] = 'O';
*(pvowels + 4) = 'U';

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%c ", pvowels[i]);
}

printf("\n");

free(pvowels);
```

Comment: All code needs to be inside of a function.

Comment: @dbush Thanks! You can submit that as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, all executable code must reside in a function.  Only variable declarations with a constant initializer may exist outside of a function.

Put this code inside of a `main` function, which is the starting point for a C program.  Also, you'll need the relevant `#include` directives for the functions you're using.

```
#include <stdio.h>      // for printf
#include <stdlib.h>     // for malloc,free

int main()
{
    // you code here
    return 0;
}
```